# Cambiar Texto mediante childnodes

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<ul id="lista">
        <li>Estudiante</li>
        <li>Pedro</li>
        <li >Julio</li>
        <li>Benites</li>
        <li >Valencia</li>
        <li>Tachira</li>
      </ul>

let nodoPadre = document.getElementsByClassName("lista");

let segundoHijo = nodoPadre.childNodes[6];

segundoHijo.innerHTML =  'NUEVO';
```

Debo editar un texto de mi lista mediante el DOM. Sin agregar id a la li, quiero hacerlo mediante childnodes.

Comment: Deseas editar alguno de los <li> que ya tienes en tu html o deseas anexar un nuevo <li>?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he entendido, creo que quieres algo asi:

```js
let nodoPadre = document.getElementById("lista");
let hijos = nodoPadre.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < hijos.length; i++) {
  if (hijos[i].innerText == "Valencia") {
    hijos[i].innerText = "NUEVO"
    break;
  }
}

// crear nueva linea
const nueva_linea = document.createElement("li");
const texto_nuevo_linea = document.createTextNode("Nueva linea");
nueva_linea.appendChild(texto_nuevo_linea);
nodoPadre.appendChild(nueva_linea)
```

```html
<ul id="lista">
  <li>Estudiante</li>
  <li>Pedro</li>
  <li>Julio</li>
  <li>Benites</li>
  <li>Valencia</li>
  <li>Tachira</li>
</ul>
```

Cambios realizados:

1. He cambiado el `getElementsByClassName` por `getElementById` pues `lista` era un **id** y no una clase en tu ejemplo *html*.
2. He asignado la variable `hijos` a todos los hijos para luego recorrerlos en un bucle.
3. He agregado un bucle para recorrerlos.
4. Dentro del bucle he puesto un ejemplo de como encontrar, mediante la propiedad `innetText`, un nodo concreto de la lista y cómo modificarlo.
5. Una vez hecho esto salimos del bucle pues ya no necesitamos continuarlo mediante `break;`
6. Y más abajo te he puesto un ejemplo de como crear una nueva linea usando `createElement`, `createTextNode` y `appendChild`

Ya nos diras si te vale.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, tú estás intentando seleccionar el elemento por su clase:

```
let nodoPadre = document.getElementsByClassName("lista");
```

PERO, el elemento no tiene `class="lista"` para poder hacer eso.

Luego, no sé por qué piensas que esto se resuelve con childNodes ¿? Si lees [la documentación, verás que quien te devuelve una lista de los **elementos** hijos es `children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), que sería todo lo que necesitarías aquí para modificar el contenido de alguno de los `li`.

Entonces, si quieres obtener los hijos de ese `ul` alcanzándolos por la clase, debes asignarle una clase. Además, debes poner un índice, porque el selector por clases te trae un array (empezando en la posición `0`) con todos los elementos que tengan ese clase, aunque sea uno.

Por la convención de nombre se entiende que quisieras cambiar el valor del segundo hijo. Entonces, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
let allChildren = document.getElementsByClassName("lista")[0].children;
allChildren[1].textContent='NUEVO';
```

```html
<ul id="lista" class="lista">
        <li>Estudiante</li>
        <li>Pedro</li>
        <li >Julio</li>
        <li>Benites</li>
        <li >Valencia</li>
        <li>Tachira</li>
      </ul>
```

---

Y, si quieres alcanzar el elmento por su id, puedes hacerlo así:

```js
let allChildren = document.getElementById("lista").children;
allChildren[1].textContent='NUEVO';
```

```html
<ul id="lista">
        <li>Estudiante</li>
        <li>Pedro</li>
        <li >Julio</li>
        <li>Benites</li>
        <li >Valencia</li>
        <li>Tachira</li>
      </ul>
```

### Post-Data

Si requieres selecciones más complejas, te recomiendo usar mejor `querySelector` y `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Ya no es lo que piensa de si se tiene que hacer con childnodes o no, es que lo pone específicamente en la redacción de su pregunta (será un ejercicio con premisas).

Comment: realmente en el enunciado solo dice que quiere hacerlo con childnodes mas no dice que es obligatorio.

Comment: @masterguru puede que sea un ejercicio, sólo que OP no lo especifica, solamente dice *quiero*, puede ser porque OP piensa que esa es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Realmente en un contexto de ejercicio no le veo demasiado sentido a querer hacerlo con childNodes, a no ser que el profesor explique luego las diferencias. Por ejemplo, para modificar el contenido, bastaría con traer **los elementos**. Si lees [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762386/5587982) verás todo lo que trae `childNodes`, mientras que `children` trae solamente el elemento (1), que es lo que se necesita aquí.

Comment: @A.Cedano solo lo decia por si no te habias dado cuenta, no es que sea partidario de una cosa u otra, de hecho antes de este "ejercicio" apenas habia jugado con los nodos.  Pero si puedo me ciño a lo que preguntan, pues deduzco que si lo ponen sus motivos tendran, y en todo caso hago otras recomendaciones al final de mi respuesta (si es que tengo algo que aportar, y en este caso no lo tenia, pero tu si pues conoces mejor el tema de los nodos) o bien via comentarios.

Comment: @A.Cedano pero para mi, viendo el perfil del OP y las 3 preguntas que lleva hoy, diria que esta haciendo ejercicios.

Comment: @masterguru quizá sea un ejercicio, ya OP confirmará. Lo bueno de SO es que se pueden aportar diferentes puntos de vista, ya OP, en base a su contexto, verá lo que mejor le conviene. Ten en cuenta que una pregunta no se limita a un usuario. Puede que, en otro contexto que no sea de ejercicios, futuros usuarios necesiten hacer algo parecido, por lo que respuestas que den otras posibilidades enriquecen la pregunta. Yo creo que cuando se trata de ejercicios conviene que los usuarios lo indiquen con claridad en la pregunta, y que en la respuesta se debería hacer referencia a que es un ejercicio.

Comment: @A.Cedano sí, me parece muy bien ese planteamiento. Ofrecer soluciones alternativas a lo preguntado desde mi punto de vista es bueno. Tan solo intento ceñirme a lo que entiendo que dicen en [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) de donde extraigo este texto que es el que me lleva a decir lo que he comentado al principio:  **Contesta la pregunta Lee la pregunta cuidadosamente. ¿Qué es lo que se está preguntando específicamente? Asegurarte de que tu respuesta incluya la solución a esto.**  Yo solo intento hacerlo bien, pero comparto completamente lo que dices.

Comment: @masterguru yo también estoy de acuerdo contigo. De todos modos creo que en la pregunta faltan detalles. Por ejemplo, según la *convención de nombre* parecería que OP quiere modificar el texto del **segundo elemento**. Y luego, lo de *quiero* hacerlo así, convendría que agregue *porque es un ejercicio*, así uno sabría a qué atenerse.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí, esta claro que le faltan detalles, los nuevos OP no saben como funciona el sitio y cuesta meterse en su piel y entenderlos muchas veces. Por eso intento hacer ejercicios de empatía poniendome en su lugar y "adivinar" lo que piden. A veces acierto y otras no :-) Borramos los comentarios?

Comment: @A.Cedano Como último apunte, a continuación del texto que antes he remarcado en negrita, esas mismas normas dicen esto: **Y si no, provee una alternativa viable. La respuesta puede ser “no hagas eso” pero debe también incluir “trata esto en vez”. Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta.**  Es decir, te dan toda la razón. En fin, fallo mio una vez más por leerme las cosas en diagonal, mis disculpas.